# SRSS Link Generate CSV File with username and password

Tags: reporting-services

We got on the report server a report that it gonna generate a CSV file. The link is:

http://reportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Reports%20Temporary/SugarAPI&acccode=ABC&rs:Format=CSV

The problem is when they click the link they got a prompt with username and password. How the username and password be embedded in the link?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot embed username and password to the link, but if the user has permission to download report and if your users are authenticating under Domain, you can enable simple feature of Internet Explorer not to prompt password.

- Go under Internet Options and Select Security Tab
- Cick on Custom Level
- Go to User Authentication Section
- Select `Automatic logon with current username and password`

then users can authenticate without using username and password

If you are going to use this URI inside your backend application, SSRS has its own SOAP Services which you can use to get authenticated to report server and download CSV file.

Comment: The users they are authenticating under Domain and they gonna be a few that they gonna need access to it. It's there any way to make the report public so everyone could generate with a link without username and password?

Comment: AFAIK anonymous authentication is not supported, you need to consider implementing custom Authorization Provider. But my solution is quick and fast. let them authenticate automatically if they are under domain

Comment: OK, thank you for your help. I'm gonna try out like that.

Comment: If you feel that my answer is useful please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer. Thank you :))